# Why is attr_accessor making my methods private?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, private, attr-accessor

I'd like to define attr_accessor on a class dynamically, but it makes the generated methods private. How can I make the following not throw an error without using the normal class syntax or writing the methods myself?

```
klass = Class.new
klass.send(:attr_accessor, 'name')
instance = klass.new
instance.name

NoMethodError: private method `name' called for #<#<Class:0x007fce725ec660>:0x007fce72607b18>
```

Comment: are you using ruby 2.0?

Comment: Just tried your snipped and it works with MRI 2.1.0. What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I tried it with version 1.9.3 and also worked. But then tried ruby 2.0 and I got the same error as you.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I am using ruby 2.0.0. I can upgrade it if I really need to.

Comment: @KarlGlaser any reason you are not passing a block to `Class.new` when creating the `class`, that seems more like what is done in the documentation

Comment: Well, I've tested now in ruby 2.1.0 and got the same error.

Comment: @bjhaid I can do it that way, thanks.

Comment: @bjhaid You should post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I just did as requested

Comment: This also happens when using Ruby 1.9.2p320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described  in the examples from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Class.html), `Class.new` is passed a block, so I would do as below:

```
klass = Class.new do
  attr_accessor :name
end

instance = klass.new
instance.name = "Foo"
instance.name #=> "Foo"
```